# Dynamic import module and css-modules(React, Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, css-modules

I want to understand the work of css-modules + dynamic modules. I have a global Button component that is used throughout the application. There is also some form (a modal window with a form) that uses a Button and is imported into the application via dynamic modules. The problem is that when the form opens, i.e. a dynamic module is loaded onto the page, the styles of this dynamic component get to the very bottom of the page, which leads to a repeated redefinition of css.

**Code Examples:**

```
// button.module
.button {
  margin: 0;
}

// Button.js
import React from 'react';
import styles from './button.module.css';

// using styles
export function Button({ className = '', onClick = () => {} }) {
    return (
            <button 
              className={`${styles.button} ${className}`} 
              onClick={onClick}
            >
             Button text
            </button>
    )
}
```

Dynamic component:

```
// form.module.css
.form__button
{
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

// Form.js component
import React from 'react';
import styles from './form.module.css';

export function Form() {
  return (
    <>
      ...
      <Button className={styles.form__button}/>
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```

Client code:

```
// page.module.css
.page__button {
  margin: 20px 0;
}


// Client code
import React from 'react';
import styles from './page.module.css';
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

// Dynamic form component
const Form = dynamic(() =>
  import("@/compoents/Form").then((mod) => mod.Form)
);

export function Page() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
<>
  ...
  {show ? <Form /> : null}
  // before show form margin for button '20px 0'
  <Button
    className={styles.page__button}
    onClick={() => setShow(true)}
  />
  // after show form margin for button '10px 0 0'
</>
```

);
}

In this case, the problem will be that when the Form component is loaded, the styles for the Button will also be loaded down  and will override our styles.form__button styles. The only solution I see is to use a local Button component, which will actually be used only for this component and contain minimal styles, layout. But this option seems to me not quite correct. I will be glad of any help

Comment: Your `Button` declaring should look like `function Button({ className }) { ... }`. Components props are passed as an object to the component.

Comment: @juliomalves, I know, thanks for clarifying. In this context, it is not important. The question was completely different. If this point is fundamental for someone, I will correct it

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25456 @AleksandrShipulin is this the issue? I just fired up this example locally... and I'm kind of shocked. or this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20203

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita, Yes, the first option, that's right. Thanks for the tip. I think I will continue to track the branch with the problem. I was just looking for this problem directly in the css-modules repository :D